# GitHub Deploy Keys - ssh -T git@github.com success but git pull still asks for password

Tags: git, github, deployment

I am trying to add a deployment key to my github repository.
The repository is private.
I have added the key to github for the repository then I have ran the following command.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Then i received the response....

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.128)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 11:22:aa:aa:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:00:11:22.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.128' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi Username/Project_Name! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Which would suggest it has worked successfully... Then I try the following

```
git pull
```

Then i get the response...

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Looking in `/var/log/auth.log` I see the following bits which don't make much sense to me...

```
May 30 16:34:13 ip-172-31-16-221 sshd[2334]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
May 30 16:35:34 ip-123-123-123-123 sshd[2336]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure git remote is in SSH, not HTTPS format? Could you show what `git remote show origin -n` tells you?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 0):

Run `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@github.com` to add the authenticity to your known_hosts.

It should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Git supports variety of protocols to communicate with remote repositories, the main ones are HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, and GIT. You can find in-depth description of these protocols in [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) book. The concrete protocol used for remote is determined by URL used to describe it.

git-push(1) lists URL formats you can use for git remotes:

- HTTP(S):

  - `http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
- SSH:

  - `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/`
  - `[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/`

You can get remote URL by executing:

```
$ git remote show <remote> -n
```

You are trying to use SSH public-key infrastructure with HTTPS remote, which is why it's not working. To resolve this issue change the URL for remote:

```
$ git remote set-url <remote> git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```